# Errors on global struct Init in C

Tags: c

In one of my files, I try to init a global struct in this way:

```
MyGlobalStruct InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct;
InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct.SomeVariable = False; <<Errors>>
```

And get a bunch of errors:
This declaration has no storage class or specifier.
The declaration is incompatible with previous line
Expected a ";"

When I do it in a function:

```
void InitMyGlobalStruct()
{
    InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct.SomeVariable = False;
}
```

I get no errors, why is that?

Edit: how is it different from :

```
uint a = 5;
```

That global line does not get me any errors...

Comment: You cannot have code (assignment) outside of a function.

Comment: What is the difference then when i do:
int a =5; 
I get no errros.

Comment: You could use a designated initializer: `MyGlobalStruct InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct = { .SomeVariable = False };` at global scope.

Comment: @schantischul You have a type on the left, so it's not a statement, it's a declaration with an initializer. Compare `uint a; a = 5;`, that has the same form (and won't work).

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a variable in the global scope (outside any function), but must put statements that are not declarations into a function body.

This is a pure statement:

```
InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct.SomeVariable = False;
```

That's how C have been designed.

If you want to initialize your struct at global scope you could write:

```
MyGlobalStruct InstanceOfMyGlobalStruct = { .SomeVariable = False };
```

(as Jonathan mentioned)